# What's the replacement for rememberRippleIndication in JetpackCompose 1.0.0-alpha11?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In JetpackCompose 1.0.0-alpha08, the below code is legitimate, where by `indication = rememberRippleIndication(...)` is okay.

```
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier.padding(4.dp).clickable(
            onClick = { },
            indication = rememberRippleIndication(
                color = color.value.rippleColor()
            )
        )
    ) {
    }
```

However in 1.0.0-alpha11, the `indication` parameter doesn't exist anymore for `clickable`, and the `rememberRippleIndication` also doesn't exist. What's the replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use another [`Modifier.clickable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#clickable_1) which also requires `InteractionState`.

Also `rememberRippleIndication` has been deprecated and replaced with `rememberRipple`.

```
Surface(
    modifier = modifier.padding(4.dp).clickable(
        onClick = { },
        indication = rememberRipple(
            color = color.value.rippleColor()
        ),
        interactionState = remember { InteractionState() }
    )
) { }
```

Comment: indication is also not available in clickable anymore :(

Comment: When I add `interactionState`, magically, `indication` is now available. Cool!